# Why does the phone light up at times but other times it's dark with a green dot?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Why does the phone light up at times () and others it just black with a green dot next to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The grey dot and a device shown with the display off is used when the device is offline and cannot be tracked with Find My iPhone.
- The green dot and a device shown with the display on is when the device is actively reporting its location to Find My iPhone.

A green dot and an 'off' display as you mention in your question is mutually exclusive.